# FullCalendar [Add Row On Timeline Column]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

[image]

In above pictures, I wanna add row column on Time Column(Full Calendar).
my code looks like below:

```
  calendarOptions: {
    locale: 'ja',
    plugins: [interactionPlugin, timeGridPlugin, resourceTimelinePlugin],
    initialView: 'resourceTimeline',
    nowIndicator: true,
    editable: true,
    expandRows: true,
    slotMinTime: '07:00:00',
    slotMaxTime: '21:00:00',
    resourceAreaHeaderContent: ' ',
    initialEvents: [{ title: 'nice event', start: new Date() }],
    resources: [
      { id: 1, title: 'test１' },
      { id: 2, title: 'test１' },
      { id: 3, title: 'test１' },
      { id: 4, title: 'test１' },
      { id: 5, title: 'test１' },
    ],
    resourceAreaWidth: 200,
    slotDuration: '01:00',
  },
```

Comment: That isn't possible exactly the way you've drawn it. I'd suggest adding these items as a feed of (recurring?) events to a resource which you place first in your list. That way at least they'll be just underneath the times - that's as close as you'll get.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.